# IIS 404 dynamic redirect

Tags: iis, redirect, server-side

Question for you guys.
If I am capturing a 404 error through an isapi filter in IIS and calling a handler with code to redirect the user by taking in their url request as a parameter and running a query on the database.  Can I run into issues making that dynamic server side redirect if multiple users are being caught by the error handler simultaneously.  I believe the first execution is being terminated, the second one completes, and both users are redirected to the same url.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am capturing a 404 error through an isapi filter in IIS...

I am not clear if you are *writing* the filter, or if the filter already exists. I'll assume you are writing it yourself since this is stackoverflow, and I'll assume C or C++ since you said ISAPI.

In *that* case....An ISAPI filter will get an [HTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524517.aspx) for each request incoming request. You need to structure your code so as to keep those things separate; pass the pointer to that structure around to each function in your code, if using C, or store it in object state if using C++.  Also your code needs to be thread-safe.

> Can I run into issues making that dynamic server side redirect if multiple users are being caught by the error handler simultaneously.

Yes, if you don't follow the requirements for writing a multi-threaded filter.

---

There are simpler ways to accomplish what you want, I think.  [IIS allows administrators to specify URLs to deliver a "custom HTTP Error Response"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731570%28WS.10%29.aspx). The URL can be anything on the webserver, including a dynamic web script, like a page written in ASPNET or PHP or whatever. You may want to use a 302 redirect to your dynamic page; that's a common pattern. There's no need to resort to writing an ISAPI filter.